# Downloading Pyscripter problem?

Tags: python, download, pyscripter

I keep trying to download Pyscripter on my 32bit Netbook, and I keep getting a range of errors such as "The installation package could not be opened". Any clue on how to make pyscripter work?

Comment: You might be getting a corrupt download. Check the checkdums. Also, you might be downloading a file for a platform other than your own. Also, this is a question for superuser rather than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your download is not corrupt:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> f = open("PyScripter-v2.3.3-Setup.exe","rb")
>>> s = hashlib.sha1(f.read())
>>> f.close()
>>> s.hexdigest()
'dda9da0bb466c28db804c7989d14329c25cdcec8'
>>>
```